# Connection string for local database in C#

Tags: c#, .net

Maybe it's repetitive but I googled and didn't find my answer.

I developed a program by .net that has a local database (Express) that works excellently on my computer, but when I create a setup and installation, it can't insert or update and so on for example in `Delete()` method I have

```
try
{
}
catch
{
}
```

in the `exe`file always goes to the `catch{}` section and I don't know why :((

This is my connection string:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30
```

This is one of my methods for example:

```
private Boolean Delete(int id)
{
    //String conString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Parnian\\documents\\visual studio 2017\\Projects\\Bank\\Bank\\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(Connection);
    String sqll = "Delete FROM TblBank WHERE  Id =@id ";

    try
    {
        sql.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqll, sql);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", id);
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        sql.Close();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBoxEx.Show("have some problem", "wrong", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return false;
    }
}
```

and Necessary say i put my `.mdf` and `.ldf` file into my setup folder and make setup by Visual Studio Installer

Comment: Hi, can you show the exception?

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: Does the computer you installed it on have a  LocalDB?

Comment: @paparazzo hi how can i know that?? i  see that in some sites but dont know what that mean!!! i must installe local databace in every computer that i want install my program??

Comment: @Stefan hi dont have eception just go to catch{} section and just show a message box that i declare

Comment: It means your connection string is to LocalDB so there has to be one and SQL Server.  And if you get that message box then you do have an Exception.

Comment: `always go to catch{} section and i don't know why` The exception will tell you what the problem is if you examine it rather than just report "have some problem"

Comment: Your code is obviously using **SQL Server** (the "LocalDB" version of it) as its database - if you want to run this on another PC, that PC **must have** that same version of SQL Server installed - otherwise, this will **never** work ....

Comment: @parnian: You **do** need to learn how to handle and read your exceptions. It is there, where you show the `MessageBox`. It will help you to solve this, *and* other problems.

Comment: @Stefan You did not understand the question, in my computer and wile debuging its work true but when i install it has problem Try to help others not to hurt their spirits

Comment: @parnian: I am not trying to hurt you; I am trying to tell you that it is worth the effort to learn how you can get information out of the exception. It will help you in the future. The exception will tell you what's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
private bool Delete(int id)
{
    string connString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Parnian\\documents\\visual studio 2017\\Projects\\Bank\\Bank\\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    String sql = "Delete FROM TblBank WHERE  Id =@id ";
    try
    {
        sqlConn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlConn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", id);
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sql.Close();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBoxEx.Show(ex.Message, "wrong", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return false;
    }
}
```

So that you can see what the error is. At the moment you are just saying something went wrong when `ex` contains everything you will need to debug the problem.

Hope this helps.

(There are a few things to refactor too, such as wrapping your connection in a `using` statement.)

Comment: I just saw that you don't have SQL installed on the machine? That's your problem right there. Install it on any machine using the application, or put it on a central server (or cloud service like Azure) and connect to that.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of your problem is very simple. There can be two situations in your case. They are as follows:

1. The computer you are trying to run the application doesn't have the proper version of the sql server.

   **Solution:** In this case, you have to find out in which sql server version you have created your database. Then you have to include that version of sql server into the setup.exe package. So that when the setup.exe executes the proper sql server also setups with your application.
2. The computer you are trying to setup the application has proper sql version but still you are getting the error.

   **Solution:** First delete your existing database and create new database from solution explorer.Then use this particular `connection string given below`

   SqlConnection conn = new 
   SqlConnection  (global::`ProjectName`.Properties.Settings.Default.`ProjectConnectionString`);

`ProjectConnectionString` can be found in `App.config` file after you connect your database to your solution.

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask in the comment if you need to.

Comment: hi my friend add some detail pleas

Comment: @parnian It does not get any simpler than you need SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

**@Parnian** It should required to install local db in your system.
1.when you click server object explorer and then when  you  click on Localdb server you will get proper connection string from properties .

```
enter code here  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestConncetion testConncetion = new TestConncetion(Delete);//here I used delegate

        WriteLine($"My connection string is working Fine ,result is {testConncetion(1)}");
    }

    private static bool Delete(int id)
    {
        string Connection = @"Data Source=(localdb)\ProjectsV13;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False";
        //String conString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Parnian\\documents\\visual studio 2017\\Projects\\Bank\\Bank\\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(Connection);
        string sqll = "Delete FROM TblBank WHERE  Id =@id ";
        try
        {
            sql.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqll, sql);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", id);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sql.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteLine("have some problem", "wrong", ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
```